# CORREGIR CÓDIGO DE BOTON PLAY/PAUSE DE UN VIDEO

Tags: javascript, html5, ccs, función-personalizada, typeerror

tengo un problema con un fragmento de código que tengo que corregir y no le encuentro forma (aun soy novato en Js). La cuestión es que el video no se auto reproduce cuando ingreso a la pagina, por otro lado no se esta ejecutando bien el rol de "play y pause" en el video, además no quisiera que se vea la barra de reproducción en ningún momento... les dejo el código a ver si pueden decirme que estoy haciendo mal, desde ya muchas gracias.

```
var mivideo = document.getElementById('video_desktop');

funcionvideo();
  
 $('#inicio_pausa').click(funcionvideo);
  
      function funcionvideo()
      {   
        mivideo = document.getElementById('video_desktop');
          if(mivideo.paused)  
          { 
              mivideo.play();  
              $("#inicio_pausa button").empty();
              $("#inicio_pausa button").append('<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>');
              $("#inicio_pausa span").empty();
              $("#inicio_pausa span").text("Pause video"); }
          else
          {  
              mivideo.pause(); 
              $("#inicio_pausa button").empty();
              $("#inicio_pausa button").append('<i class="fas fa-play"></i>'); 
              $("#inicio_pausa span").empty();
              $("#inicio_pausa span").text("Play video"); 
          }
      };
});
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún error en consola del navegador?

Comment: si, cuando pongo para inspeccionar me salen errores.

Comment: otra cosa que agregar que es una web hecha con WordPress, pero le metieron mano con código y bueno, ese es el resultado, han insertado ese código para un video que no esta linkeado sino que esta alojado en la misma web. A intentado editar la acción de play/pause de manera manual con código